# Would XDES be more secure than 3DES, where X is a number > 3?

Tags: des, 3des

Would XDES be more secure than 3DES, where X is a number  > 3? 
Like 10DES... If so why aren't we using it?

Comment: related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/32778/is-a-4des-or-5des-system-possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would XDES be more secure than 3DES, where $X > 3$ ?

Yes. [This answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/32779/45423) about if 4DES / 5DES is possible illustrates it quite well.

It would however make *more* sense, if you really want to make it more secure, to have $n$-DES, where $n = 2k-1 \space | \space k \in \mathbb{N}$, or in simple terms: $n$-DES, where $n$ is an odd number.

This comes from the [Meet-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack) (MITM attack).

Example:

DES has a keylength of $2^{56}$. Double DES only has a keylength of $2^{57} (= 2 \times 2^{56})$. Only by using 3DES you start to really improve the security from single-DES: $2^{56} \times 2^{56} + 2^{56} \approx 2^{112}$.

> Why aren't we using XDES with large X?

Because of [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard). It's not *feasible* to have MITM-attack on AES.

Using XDES instead of AES would have more drawbacks than benefits, especially from a computational view.

Comment: You can also add the small block-size; [sweet32](https://sweet32.info/)

Comment: Meet-in-the-middle attack requires the attacker to know the plaintext, how can the attacker already know the plaintext without decrypting the ciphertext?